# jQuery - when slideToggle is up, do function

Tags: jquery

How can I make jQuery do a function when slideToggle is going up?

Currently I have this:

```
$('#yearly').click(function () {
    var height = $('.span8').outerHeight(true);
    $('.side-box').css({height: '797'});
    $('.yearlyc').slideToggle();     



});
```

Whenever someones clicks on #yearly, then .side-box is adjusting the height. I want to do this as well then slideToggle goes up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the callback function and check the visibility of the element:

```
$('.yearlyc').slideToggle(function() {
    if ( $(this).is(':hidden') ) {
      // ...
    }
});
```

If there are several elements you can use `.promise()` method, so the handler is called once:

```
$('.yearlyc').slideToggle().promise().done(function(o) {
    if ( this.is(':hidden') ) {
      // ...
    }
});
```